# How to solve a data source error when loading Google Analytics data in Power BI?

Tags: google-analytics, datasource, powerbi-desktop, internal-server-error

I would like to load data from Google Analytics into Power BI.
After transforming the data in the Query Editor, I apply the changes.
At first, I see the message 'Waiting for www.googleapis.com' and the number of rows increases.
After a while, I get the following error message:

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] There was an internal error..'

Rows with errors have been removed in one of the steps and I have a stable Internet connection.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this kind of refreshing issue, First go to edit query and verify the data types and change the data types if needed, after that if you still facing this error, you need to keep open the app.powerbi.com while refresh your PBI dashboard, I was followed the above steps and my issue got resolved now.